# BlackBerry BIS Push Notification Not Received By Devices in Asia

Tags: blackberry, push-notification

We are developing a BB app using the Verivo development platform. The application server pushes notifications using the settings provided by RIM after registering for BIS Push. We have observed that BB devices in the US are receiving the notifications successfully. However devices in Asia (Singapore and Sri Lanka) are not. These devices have valid BIS plans and are properly connected to BIS. What could be the issue?

We did tick all three regions when registering with push.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the new BIS registration status after the failed attempt, and the error description if available?

Comment: most issues that we saw were on our side - we didn't send correct push destination or bb didn't register to the push or something else

Comment: Hi Eugen Thanks this indeed seemed to be the case. The cause was a corrupt config database left over in the BB. Cleared this out reinstalled and it worked. Verivo support helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The cause was a corrupt config database left over in the BB. Verivo support recommended not installing the app using the BB Desktop Manager which may cause this issue. Cleared this out reinstalled and it worked.